# Share ejb jar file with multiple wars in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm aware that this is a very simple issue, but as I'm new to Wildfly I haven't had success trying to accomplish it.

In the old days of JBoss 4.2, when I wanted to share an ejb jar file with multiple war files I just deployed the ejb jar file to the application server and configured jndi in my war projects with a file 'jndi.properties' placed in some source directory in the war files, like this:

```
jndi.properties
---------------
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
```

Now, with Wildfly 8.1, this approach is not working anymore. I don't know if the contents of the jndi properties file changed or if I have to do something else. So, I ask: how do I share an ejb jar file with multiple wars in Wildfly 8.1 (I don't want to use ear files for this)?

Thank you in advance.

Marcos

PS.: Cross-posted: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249133

Comment: Please show the injection/lookup code and include the `@Remote` interfaces and their implementation you are using.

Answer (score 3):

just deploy the jar file and add adependency to your war file (either in Manifest.MF or in jboss-deployment-structure.xml from your war to your jar. Then you should be able to do JNDI-lookups using java:global/... or using CDI for injecting the beans using @Inject (for this approach you will need to activate CDI using beans.xml)

see also:

- [Wildfly class loading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)
- [Wildfly deployment descriptors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly)
- [CDI reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CDI+Reference)
- [Application deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Application+deployment)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and references. I'll test that later.